# Xcode snapshots - Discard change

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode4.5, snapshot

I am wondering why every change during restoring a snapshot is greyed out for discarding.
I would like to restore my project to a previous snapshot but keep some of my new changes (so they appear in the old project).

Anybody knows?

Comment: Just a suggestion for the future... Use Xcode's built in local Git repository for version control.

Comment: OK, I will.. but what to do now? :)

Comment: As I understand, nobody uses this feature... :)